# Why does the .Net world seem to embrace magic strings instead of staticly typed alternatives?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, static-typing, xaml

So, I work in .Net. I make open source projects in .Net. One of my biggest problems with it isn't necessariyl with .Net, but with the community and frameworks around it. It seems everywhere that magical naming schemes and strings is treated as the best way to do everything. Bold statement, but look at it:

ASP.Net MVC:

Hello world route:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

What this means is that ASP.Net MVC will somehow look up `HomeController` in your code. Somehow make a new instance of it, and then call the function `Index`  apparently with an `id` parameter of some sort. And then there are other things like:

```
RenderView("Categories", categories);
...or..
ViewData["Foobar"]="meh";
```

And then there are similar things with XAML as well. `DataContext` is treated as an object and you have to hope and pray that it resolves to the type you want. DependencyProperties must use magic strings and magic naming conventions. And things like this:

```
  MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
  Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");
  myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
```

Although it relies more on casting and various magical runtime supports.

Anyway, I say all that to end up here: Why is this so well tolerated in the .Net world? Aren't we using statically typed languages to almost always know what the type of things are? Why is reflection and type/method/property/whatever names(as strings) prefered so much in comparison to generics and delegates or even code generation?

Are there inherit reasons that I'm missing for why ASP.Net's routing syntax relies almost exclusively on reflection to actually resolve how to handle a route? I hate when I change the name of a method or property and suddenly things break, but there don't appear to be any references to that method or property and there are of course no compiler errors. Why was the apparent convenience of magic strings considered "worth it"?

I know there are also commonly statically typed alternatives to some things, but they usually take a backseat and seem to never be in tutorials or other beginner material.

Comment: Pointless dynamism has been all the rage ever since our CPUs were fast enough to execute it.

Comment: I can understand if you choose a dynamic language like Ruby, you can bet that types won't be deterministic and they'll be a lot of metaprogramming. The language was built for it and the framework will take advantage. However, for ASP.Net MVC for instance, it's designed to run on statically typed C#. Why must it use so much metaprogramming to actually work? You'd think a static framework for a static language just like every dynamic language usually has only dynamic frameworks

Comment: You forgot to add that Linq enforces the same bad, magic-string type habits as well.

Comment: How so? I've not seen any such examples with LINQ.

Comment: My humble guess is that the properly statically typed alternative is too freaking inconvenient. That's a theme that turns up a lot with most type systems really: "We'd like to do this in the type system, but it's not expressive enough." (Or the inverse: "We successfully expressed this in the type system, but it made things three times as complex.") @GlenH7 I'm not terribly familiar with all of LINQ, but the bits I've used don't exhibit anything even near what this post describes. Care to give an example?

Comment: @GlenH7 In some cases it encourage anonymous objects... but those objects aren't really passed around everywhere in most cases so it doesn't matter much

Comment: @Earlz More importantly, anonymous objects are statically typed. There are no magic strings, the compiler knows the name and type of everything involved. Save for every other use of `var`.

Comment: @delnan I've been implementing my own MVC framework that is statically typed through and through and it's really NOT that inconvienent though. I'd think relying on so much reflection would make things harder to implement

Comment: @delnan well, the compiler does, but all that compile-time checking is negated when you pass it somewhere as an object and treat it's property/method names as strings

Comment: It's because people dislike noise

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Earlz when you think about your business, complex accounting system, customers, products, trading, time schedules and what not - writing countless lines of "public static void external template <> class property get; set; interface implements abstract inherits" just pisses you off. easier to spit out simple convention and just follow it.

Comment: The deleted answer by @brian actually has the answer embedded in it. Generally, people do not know how to to it any other way, and those that do, don't think it though because it's easier to copy type / cut'n'paste etc from a text book or google search results.  - read up "The story of five Gorillas" - Those doing it today are being Gorillas .

Comment: just about anything in this thread implies that static>dynamic.

Comment: Can anyone provide equally (or more so) succint, but type safe alternatives here?  My feeling is that you'd have at least some additional bloat.

Comment: @ArnisL. I'm not saying it is. I am saying I prefer static to dynamic though.

Comment: @DanielB it's possible, albeit not as trivial. For example my POC type-safe fluent API for routing https://gist.github.com/Earlz/4951054

Comment: @Earlz that's interesting, although one could argue that the lambda syntax is the additional bloat here.  My guess is they went with the magic string / convention approach because it's dead simple, "good enough" for many, and they can always adapt the tooling to give some guidance / safety.  It's a trade off between safety and convenience, IMHO.  The use of a dynamic ViewBag also hint at this mentality (not that I fully agree with it).

Comment: @DanielB I can understand that viewpoint. Just seems like something that is really awesome to give a demo and say "this is how easy it is to get started".. but then when you need to refactor it's another story

Comment: @Earlz I hear you; it'd be great to have a bit more safety.  That said, the entire ecosystem is a bit difficult to verify at compile time - e.g. if you change a base template, is the jQuery selector used by some arbitrary child template still valid (and how do you verify this)?  Still, at least the compiled parts should be verifiable.

Comment: @DanielB in theory, it's possible to make everything type-safe, even Javascript, but practically it'd make development such a huge pain that no one would use it

Comment: Well i don't see how you'd build a class to represent the route that wouldn't be a nightmare to work with.  I'd avoid ViewData whenever possible, and the argument to RenderView could become a constant.  Finally, for xaml, i wouldn't write the binding in code like that, it'd be in the Xaml and I'd use the designer (code gen) to setup bindings.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Actually there is a push back in the .NET world against these very things you mentioned. In the first example you gave however, the routing engine is given a convention for mapping the default route. The very fact that the routes are dynamic make it nigh impossible to use a static configuration.

You also mention XAML/WPF, both of which were under development well before generics were introduced into .NET and going back to support generics would have delayed an already very late product (Longhorn/Vista) even further.

There are examples within the ASP.NET MVC framework of using lambda expressions in place of magic strings and the Entity Framework/LINQ takes it even further where the language and framework provides native support for composing SQL queries over a static object graph (instead of constructing magic SQL strings, you get compile time validation of your queries).

For other examples of static configuration see structuremap and other modern dependency injection containers, and other frameworks that need to inspect the object graph at runtime but allow the developer to statically provide hints using lambda expressions.

So the short answer is that historically, .NET did not support static traversal of an object graph until the 3.5 release. Now that we have it, many developers prefer it over magic strings and many have been pushing for even deeper support such as a symbolOf operator that works similar to the typeOf operator.

Comment: As far as XAML goes, you'd think they would've took the chance to improve it in WinRT since it's basically a complete rewrite anyway(which isn't API compatible). or everything else. What do you mean "routes are dynamic" though? I know you can't replace the URL pattern with some object graph, but what about the other parts? And as far as Entity Framework/Linq, I've experienced this. Very awesome being able to change your database and suddenly get compiler errors for the incompatibilities.

Comment: And I don't quite understand ".Net did not support static transversal of the object graph until the 3.5 release". Can you elaborate on what was missing? Generics arrived in 2.0

Comment: XAML is verbose as it is...adding support for generics would make it even moreso (yes I know the whole XAML isn't made for humans Argument). Besides, I see XAML as more akin to HTML than an actual programming language. It shouldn't care about the type of the objects it is displaying, just how to display it.

Comment: Generics arrived in 2.0, but we didn't get Expressions until 3.5 (with LINQ). Expressions are what power LINQ and the community has taken that power and run with it. The technique is known as [static reflection](http://www.jagregory.com/writings/introduction-to-static-reflection/)

Comment: I would tend to agree, except for it really isn't. What really made XAML click for me is that it isn't just a markup language. It's a way of describing an object graph. Although I see your point for avoiding verbosity.

Comment: Good point about static reflection. I forgot about that being introduced in 3.5

Comment: This is a great answer and I definitely agree with the pushback. All of these things I avoid like the plague because if there's a typo or bug they are only caught at runtime, meaning they can very easily be missed. They also make refactoring extremely different. Avoid avoid avoid!

Comment: Agree on the pushback. [T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) is a project which leaps to mind that aspires to remove a lot of strings and replace them with strongly typed code.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that the ASP.NET MVC Futures library (i.e. the next version in progress) adds lambda based methods for things like ActionLink, so you can avoid hard coding controller and action strings.

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net MVC is strongly inspired by frameworks like Django and Rails originating from dynamically typed languages. Therefore it adopts a number of patterns and conventions which feel a lot more dynamic than what is usual in the .net culture, for example heavy use of reflection and `dynamic` objects. This was probably a deliberate strategic decision by MS because .net was losing mind-share among web developers compared to these platforms.